# Activity takes too much time to close

Tags: android, android-activity

I called activity B from activity A. 
When I pressed `back` button within B activity, it takes too much time to close it and turn back to A.
Is there a way to optimize it?

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (ft.ordinal() > 0) setFragment(FragmentType.values()[ft.ordinal() - 1]);
        else {
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: post your B activity code..

Comment: It is depending on the thing what you have done. Please update with the code.

Comment: Please share the code here !!

Comment: activity B code is big

Comment: are you calling onActivityResult in activity A?

Comment: @Autocrab no, activity B simple finished and after activity A focused

Comment: then check onStop(), onPause, onDestroy() methods in Activity B. Maybe there is some blocking code inside one of them.

Comment: @Autocrab thx man, in onStop i'm stopping GA and this retarding closing activity.